# Is there a way to make a multi line comment in hive scripts

Tags: hive

I know that we can make a single line comment with '--' in hiveQL(hive.sql scripts) but is there a way to make multi line comments? I need something like below

```
/*  This sentence is 
    a comment */
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As per my knowledge, multi-line comments are not supported in Hive scripts as of now.
Seems like [this JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2259) introduced only single line comments, starting with *--* in Hive 0.8

Comment: This has changed.

Answer (score 13):

No, As of now Hive support single line comment only.

Hive, Pig, Hbase are starting stage not implemented like Mangodb, Cassandra, but in next version especially for Hadoop 2.x it's possible multiple comments also.

Just use -- two dashes to make a comment in hive.

Comment: This has changed.

Answer (score 6):

Multi-line (aka "bracketed") comments should be available in Hive v2.3.0:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-15765

Comment: However, in my experience it is not working in CREATE TABLE (DDL) statements yet on v2.3.0.

Comment: I've had a lot of issues even at v3.0.1